# Can I get result of the asyncio 'shielded' task that was interrupted in wait_for() by TimeOut

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Help me please with understanding some of asyncio things.
I want to realize if its possible to do next:

I have synchronous function that for example creates some data in remote API (API can returns success or fail):

```
def sync_func(url):
   ... do something
   return result
```

I have coroutine to run that sync operation in executor:

```
async def coro_func(url)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fn = functools.partial(sync_func, url)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, fn)
```

Next I want to do smth like

1. If remote API does not respond for 1 sec, I want to start next url to be processed, but I want to know result of that first task (when API finally will send response) that was broken by timeout. I wrap coro_func() in a shield() to avoid it from cancellation. But don't have an idea how I can check result after ...

`list_of_urls = [url1, ... urlN]
 map_of_task_results = {}
 async def task_processing():
     for url in list_of_urls:
        res = asyncio.wait_for(shield(coro_func(url), timeout=1))
        if res == 'success':
            return res
            break
        else:
            map_of_task_results[url] = res
     return "all tasks were processed"`

P.S. When I'm tried to access shield(coro) result - it has CancelledError exception.. but I expect that there might be result, because I 'shielded' task.

`try:
    task = asyncio.shield(coro_func(url))
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=API_TIMEOUT)
except TimeoutError as e:
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    pending_tasks[api_details['api_url']] = task`

```
ipdb> task
<Future cancelled created at 
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:276>
ipdb> task.exception
<built-in method exception of _asyncio.Future object at 0x7f7d41eeb588>
ipdb> task.exception()
```

*** concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a future (task) out of your coroutine before you shield it, you can always check it later. For example:

```
coro_task = loop.create_task(coro_func(url))
try:
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(coro_task), API_TIMEOUT)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    pending_tasks[api_details['api_url']] = coro_task
```

You can use [`coro_task.done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.done) to check if the task has completed in the meantime and call [`result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.result) if so or `await` it if not. If needed you can even use `shield`/`wait_for` on it again, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks @user4815162342 I figured out how to process tasks those were interrupted by timeout - in common my solution now looks like:

```
def sync_func(url):
   ... do something probably long
   return result

async def coro_func(url)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fn = functools.partial(sync_func, url)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, fn)

async def waiter(pending_tasks):
    count = 60
    while not all(map(lambda x: x.done(), pending_tasks.values())) and count > 0:
        logger.info("Waiting for pending tasks..")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        count -= 1

    # Finally process results those were in pending 
    print([task.result() for task in pending_tasks.values()])

async def task_processing(...):
    list_of_urls = [url1, ... urlN]
    pending_tasks = {}

    for url in list_of_urls:
        try:
            task = asyncio.Task(coro_func(url))
            result = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(task), timeout=API_TIMEOUT)
        except TimeoutError as e:
            pending_tasks[url] = task

        if not result or result != 'success':
            continue
        else:
            print('Do something good here on first fast success, response to user ASAP in my case.')
            break

    # here start of pending task processing
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(waiter(pending_tasks))
```

So I'm collecting tasks those were interrupted by concurrent.future.TimeoutError in the dict mapping object, then I run task with waiter() coro that tries to wait 60 sec while pending tasks will get status done or 60 sec will run out.

In addition to words, my code placed into Tornado's RequestHandler and Tornado uses asyncio event loop.
So after N attempts to get fast response from one url from url's list, I can then answer to user and do not lose results of tasks those were initiated and interrupted with TimeoutError. (I can process them after I respond to the user, so that's was my main idea)

I hope it saves a lot of time for somebody looking for the same :)